# How to push this JSON to firestore and query the data?

Tags: json, angular, google-cloud-firestore

i would like to ask how do we push the JSON below into firestore in Angular?

```
      var customer =
        {
            "name": "john",
            "address": "xxxxx",
            "order": {
                "bookList": [{
                    "quantity": "3",
                    "price": "$2"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": "4",
                    "price": "$1"
                }]
            }
        }
```

At the same time, i would like to with each address, get the list of all orders from all customers. Was thinking of doing like the json below, i will get the document ID for the orders using the client's document id then i will add to the orders array.

```
 var data2 = {
            "address": "xxxxx",
            "orders": [{
                "id": "1dsd"
            },
            {
                "id": "312312"
            }]
        }
```

Im quite unsure on how to achieve these, appreciate any help and advice! It would be great if step by step instructions and explanations are provided!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://medium.com/lucas-moyer/how-to-import-json-data-into-firestore-2b370486b622) provides a great example of how to import JSON data into Firestore. The user provides a quick tutorial on how to migrate your initial database to Firestore.

I would also like to encourage you to look through this tutorial of using [Cloud Firestore in Angular with Angularfire](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-cloud-firestore-angularfire) as they will be best suited for what you may be looking for.

Additionally, I would like to point you towards the Angularfire community on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire#angularfire), as they may provide some insight on your particular implementation. This segment of their [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#4-querying-collections-in-angularfirestore) discusses ways of querying strategies that you may find useful .